# Select data from MySQL DB based on the URL example (www.example.co.uk/essex.php)

Tags: php, mysql, database, dynamic

I am very new to php and I am looking to create dynamic pages.

Basically If a person lands on www.example.co.uk/essex.php I would like to be able to add something like `<h1>Company In <?php echo $row['County']; ?>` so that it would show 
**Company In Essex** when Live and save time if I need to duplicate the page for another county or town.

So far I have setup a database in **phpmyadmin**

[Picture of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K80ue.png)

My code so far to grab the table is;

```
$dbconnect = mysqli_connect("HOST", "USER", "PASSWORD", "DB");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connection Failed:".mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}

$count_sql="SELECT * FROM areas";
$count_query=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $count_sql);
$count_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_query);
```

and then on www.example.co.uk/essex.php

```
<?php
do {
    echo $count_rs['County'];
} while ($count_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_query))
```

?>

But where I have gone wrong is it pulls all the data from the table for **County** where I only wish it to pull the county of Essex.

Please forgive me for explaining this badly.

UPDATE -

```
    $row = url2content();
extract($row);


function url2content($url = NULL){
if(is_null($url)){
if(isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) && $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]){
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}elseif(isset($_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]) && $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]){
$url = $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"];
}
if (substr($url,0,1) == '/'){
$url = substr($url,1);
}
}
if (DEBUG_MODE){
echo ('URL requested: "'.$url.'"<br>');
}



function get_towns($county){
    $query = sprintf("select townName from " . AREAS_TABLE . " where countyName = '%s'  order by rand() LIMIT 0,24" ,mysql_real_escape_string($county));
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$res){
        printf("Unable to query ".AREAS_TABLE." table: %s \n", mysql_error());
    }
    $html="";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $html.="<li>".stripslashes($row["townName"])."</li>\n";
    }
    return $html;
}}
```

Comment: $count_sql="SELECT * FROM areas WHERE country ='".$count_rs['County']."'";  you need like this.

Comment: use where clause in your query SELECT * FROM areas WHERE county='essex'

Comment: @SunilRajput That works but I need it so it would change for example if you landed on kent.php or greatermanchester.php

Comment: simple get the county name from url and store it in variable and pass into your query on the page. SELECT * FROM areas WHERE county='$county'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use WHERE clause in your query in order to select a specific country from your db
SELECT * from table WHERE felid_country=$count_rs['County'];

Comment: I cant get this to work I get the follow error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Answer (score 0):

You can use **strpos()** to match the **County** (eg.essex)  with url  **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** (eg.www.example.co.uk/essex.php)  in your case.
Just like this

```
<?php
do {
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$count_rs['County'])!=false)
    echo $count_rs['County'];
} while ($count_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_query))
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply, I have tried this but would this not defeat the purpose of having a database ?

Comment: No it will not defeat the purpose of having a database.